# On a planet with winds faster than sound, what would it sound like?

Tags: acoustics, planets

I'm watching a Youtube video of the strangest planets and some of them have atmospheres/winds that constantly go at like 20x the speed of sound, ex: HD 189733-b  .On earth, fast winds is actually pretty loud, but what happens when wind itself goes faster than the speed of sound?  Would it be silent or extremely deafening?  Would there be constant supersonic booms?

Comment: I doubt any wind can be faster than sound. That's because sound is a vibration in pressure and therefore is carried by wind. The planet you're looking at has very fast winds, 7x the speed of sound *on Earth*, but not the speed of sound on that planet.

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding. At the equator, the Earth itself rotates 37% faster than the speed of sound. This does not mean the Earth has supersonic winds at the equator (it doesn't). Nor does HD 189733-b. Voting to close.

Comment: @DavidHammen, from the NASA web page [here](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/rains-of-terror-on-exoplanet-hd-189733b):  *"The weather on this world is deadly. Its winds blow up to 5,400 mph (2 km/s) at seven times the speed of sound, whipping all would-be travelers in a sickening spiral around the planet."*

Also, there is this NASA web page: [5400mph winds discovered hurtling around planet outside solar system](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/news/232/5400mph-winds-discovered-hurtling-around-planet-outside-solar-system/)

Comment: What it would sound like depends on a huge range of factors, not least of which are density, temperature and what the *relative* velocity of the listener is to the wind.  Your specific example is awful because humans could not exist there - it's essentially a hot Jupiter-like planet.  In any case human ears are not built for constant exposure to supersonic winds of non-trivial density (and nor is the rest of the human body).

Comment: @StephenG : Assume a suitably robust microphone instead, with enough dynamic range to not clip to the point of uselessness. Ideally, invincible, linear, and unlimited dynamic range. Like massless pulleys, and so forth. Generally, I believe those who think of these kinds of questions are assuming an idealized human, otherwise the answer to _all_ of them is "nothing, you die", which is not particularly interesting even if true.